# iOS create time line view to show events

Tags: ios, uiview, uilabel

I created a timeline view, to show certain events at different times on a day.

for example, I have the array with following events:

```
   @[A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H]
```

Here these events start at different times.

A at 9am, B at 9:30am , C at 10:00am etc...

based on the time, I calculate the Y value.

Here is the method to add events to the timeline view:

```
-(void)addEvents{

       NSArray *tempArr = //dataarray;
       __block NSInteger day = idx;

        _dayeventViewArray = [NSMutableArray array];
        [tempArr enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id  _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {

            //If there are two events at the same time, then they should share the width equally
            int eventX = [self getEventXForDay://];
            int eventY = [self getEventYFor://];

            float timeLineWdith = 60;

            //Add TitleLabel
            UILabel *titleLab = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(eventX, eventY, timeLineWdith, eventViewHeight)];

            [self addSubview:titleLab];
            [_dayeventViewArray addObject:titleLab];

        }];

    [self reorderConflictingViews];

}
```

and after the events are added, I try to adjust their frames so that events don't overlap, and user can see all events.

```
-(void)reorderConflictingViews{

    float timeLineWdith = 60;

        NSMutableArray *yArray = [NSMutableArray array];

        NSArray *dayArr = //dataarray;
        __block int labelY = 0;
            [dayArr enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id  _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
                UILabel *conflictView = (UILabel *)obj;

                //if array contains 5 events, share the space equally among 5 events, so divide timeline width by 5
                int conflictViewWidth = timeLineWdith/dayArr.count;
                int originalX = conflictView.frame.origin.x;
                int newX = (int)(originalX + idx*conflictViewWidth);
                NSLog(@"orig X: %d, new X:%d",originalX,newX);
                conflictView.frame = CGRectMake(newX, conflictView.frame.origin.y, conflictViewWidth, conflictView.frame.size.height);

            }];
}
```

The result is:

[image]

The left view is what I get, but I want to achieve the right side result.

Comment: You need to calculate the width of conflictView based on overlapping events during same time. No overlapping means, full width for conflict view. Not by dividing total events count.  And when your next event does not overlap and your events are ordered based on time means, you need to reset your newX position.

Comment: You can try to add UIStackView in every row. Adding events will auto adjust the width inside stackview.